# String manipulation with batch scripting

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, space

I need to save the variable in %%c temporarily which comes from a for loop. But when I try to do that, the content changes unexpectedly. Some space characters appear at the end of the string. The content of %%c is a.jpg by the way.

```
        echo %%ca                 REM prints a.jpga

        set temp=%%c    
        set temp=!temp!

        echo !temp!a              REM prints a.jpg  a
```

I tried the code below to get rid of the extra spaces after initializing the temp variable. But it gave me an error: "=%" was unexpected at this time". What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

```
        set "this=!temp!"
        set "this=%this:* =%"
        call set "this=%%temp:%this%=%%"
        set "this=%this:~0,-1%"
        echo %this%a
```

Comment: As you know the extended syntax of `SET "var=content"` already, you should use it always.  `set "temp=%%c"`    Btw. `set temp=!temp!` is nonsense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your line `set temp=%%c` is the reason. There are spaces at the end.

Use this syntax to avoid unintended spaces:

```
set "temp=%%c"
```

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. Thank you!